# Multiple objects with same datasource and delegate functions

Tags: ios, delegates, datasource

I have drawn Pie Charts using https://github.com/Zomato/DR-charts but I have same viewcontroller for multiple charts, so how to differentiate objects in datasource and delegate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate objects for every chart and add it as delegates/data sources.Your `UIViewController` can hold them like properties.

Comment: Can you explain me how should i create different objects as I have already created different objects in view controller but i cannot differentiate them in delegates/data sources methods

Comment: i am using Swift 3 and charts have been coded in objective c